# NetLogo Links: what is a good way to filter nearby turtles by value of their link variable

Tags: netlogo

I need to see if there is any agent nearby which might have a link to a caller agent with negative relationship value , now I am using following code:

```
    if any? out-link-neighbors with [member? myself [end2] of my-out-links with [Value-Of-The-Relationship < 0]] 
        [

           Let Active_Agent self
          let Target_Agent nobody
          Let Witnesses []


          let Met  out-link-neighbors with [member? myself [end2] of my-out-links with [Value-Of-The-Relationship < 0]] 

          if any?  Met in-radius 2 [

              set Target_Agent one-of Met in-radius 2



            if some conditions

            [   
              set Witnesses other agents in-radius vision with [Belongs_to = [Belongs_to] of Active_Agent ]

              if any?  Witnesses 
                [ 
                  Let Penalty  4000 / count Witnesses


                  ask Witnesses 

                  [Update_link_Values Target_Agent Penalty]

                ]
]]]



To Update_link_Values  [Other_Agent Value]
ifelse  out-link-neighbor? Other_Agent
 [ ask out-link-to Other_Agent  
    [ 
        set Value-Of-The-Relationship Value-Of-The-Relationship + Value  
        set Frequency Frequency + 1
     ]   
    ] ;IF already has a link 
[create-link-to Other_Agent 
    [
        set Value-Of-The-Relationship Value-Of-The-Relationship + Value 
        set Frequency Frequency + 1 
        hide-link]   
        ] ;If they meet for the first time



            end
```

I have summarized the code to give you an idea of when I use ask and with , is there any better way to do it ?

all of this code is called by another procedure which only has one ask agents [], and it does exactly what I need it to do, but I thought I might have a wrong methodology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following will filter an initial group of out-neighbors before checking their end2 and therefore be a faster way to filter target candidates (it's more accurate too)

```
let met  out-link-neighbors in-cone 2 180 with [member? myself [end2] of my-out-links with [Value-Of-The-Relationship < 0]] 

        if any? Met
    []
```

another main change will be limiting witnesses, for now all agents in-radius 5 of active agent will be considered a witness, but I think its better to check if the active-agent is in their cone vision, I am still looking to find an efficient way to check witnesses vision to see if they can observe the acting agent.

```
set Witnesses other (agents in-radius vision with [Belongs_to = [Belongs_to] of Active_Agent and member? myself people in-cone vision  75 ])
```

** UPDATE : A much better answer**

```
    let met out-link-neighbors in-cone 2 120 with 
    [
[Value-Of-The-Relationship] of in-link-from myself < 0]
```

Comment: I would suggest using `let` to avoid repeating the entire computation, like: `let met out-link-neighbors ... if any? met [ ... ]`

Comment: You might try replacing `other agents in-radius vision with ...` with `other (agents in-radius vision with ...)` to see if there's any performance impact. `other` copies the agentset, so by delaying `other` to be the last operation, you may save time.

Comment: I think the `member? myself [end2] of ...` bit can be avoided; there should be a more direct way to express the thought "that guy has a out-link that points to me".  Can you use `in-out-link-neighbor?` or `out-link-neighbor?` instead?

Comment: let met  out-link-neighbors in-cone 2 180 with [in-link-from myself with [Value-Of-The-Relationship < 0]] might work, but I just thought of another way : I need to check "link [who] of myself [who] of self" I dont have netlogo right now but I will check it and let you know :)

Comment: `link [who] of myself [who] of self` reduces to just `in-link-from myself`, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: can't the `in-link-from myself != nobody` check simply be omitted? this turtle was already picked using `out-link-neighbors` from another turtle, so surely an in-link-from that turtle must exist

Comment: Yes, I think so , I was worried about behavior space errors that sometimes drive me crazy by errors that `of expected something but got nobody`!!!  So I try to be sure that it does not get `nobody` :D